# Apache2 Reverse Proxy Redirection

Tags: javascript, apache, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy, synology

I have configured an Apache reverse proxy, to connect to my Synology Nas, but it does not work. Not all queries are rewritten correctly to the new URL.

Here my Code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin email@loclahost   
ServerName server.fritz.box

ProxyHTMLEnable On

ProxyPass        /external/  http://192.168.178.99:5000/ 
ProxyPassReverse  /external/ http://192.168.178.99:5000/ 


</VirtualHost>
```

Only the page name and the Logo appears in the browser, but not the Website.

The Probelm is that the Proxy don't Rewrite the scripts:

```
<div id="sds-login-dialog-form" style="position: absolute; top: -10000px; left: -10000px;"><form id="login-form" class="x-plain-body" method="POST" action="login.cgi" target="login_iframe" onsubmit="return true;"><input type="text" id="login_username" name="username" maxlength="256" /><input type="password" id="login_passwd" name="passwd" maxlength="256" autocomplete="off" /><input type="text" id="login_otp" name="OTPcode" maxlength="8" autocomplete="off" /><input type="submit" id="login_submit" style="position: absolute; top: -10000px; left: -10000px;" tabindex="-1" /></form><iframe id="login_iframe" name="login_iframe" width="0" height="0" frameborder="0" style="display: none;"></iframe></div>
<div id="sds-apply-preview-form" style="position: absolute; top: -10000px; left: -10000px;"><form id="preview-form" class="x-plain-body" method="POST" action="modules/ControlPanel/modules/dsm.cgi" target="preview_iframe" onsubmit="return true;"><input type="submit" id="preview_submit" style="position: absolute; top: -10000px; left: -10000px;" tabindex="-1" /></form><iframe id="preview_iframe" name="preview_iframe" width="0" height="0" frameborder="0" style="display: none;"></iframe></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="synodefs.cgi?v=1420615814"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/uistrings.cgi?lang=ger&v=1427210921"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/webfm/webUI/uistrings.cgi?lang=ger&v=1427210921"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="uistrings.cgi?lang=ger&v=1427210921"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/prototype-1.6.1/prototype.js?v=1420615788"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/ext-3/adapter/ext/ext-base.js?v=1420615788"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/ext-3/ext-all.js?v=1420615788"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/ext-3/ux/ux-all.js?v=1420615788"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/scrollbar/flexcroll.js?v=1420615788"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sds.js?v=1420615813"></script>
```

Only the Scrips with no  /  at the begin of the Link are callable.

How can I Rewrite them to the new URL?
I Hope you can help me!

Sorry for my bad english :)

Best Wishes
Simon

Answer (score 0):

you might be able to use something like to only proxy the files with /script/

ProxyPassMatch ^(/scripts/.*)$ http://192.168.178.99:5000/

or if you want to proxy all that start with / although that might cause other issues

ProxyPassMatch ^(/.*)$ http://192.168.178.99:5000/

Comment: Yes, I want to proxy all.

But I will call the Proxy Page over the Proxy with the url mydomain.de/external it shoud display the page 192.168.178.99:5000 and when I call the Page mydomain.de/test it shoud display the page 192.168.178.1:80.